# how to create a function to calculate hyperbolic sine of values

Tags: matlab, function, trigonometry

I am using the matlab 2007b and getting in a problem i want to make a function that takes input argument from the user and return sine hperbolic of that value.Sine hyperbolic should be define by that formula sinh(x)=(e^x-e^-x)/2
    I am using that code while getting error

```
function sinh=sinhx(x)

% take the input value of x
    a=exp(x)
% assinge exp(x) to a
    b=exp(-1*x)
%assinge exp(-x) to variable b
    c=a-b
%getting difference of these two variables
    d=c/2
% dividing by 2 to get sinhx
    end
```

kindly guide me how can I make this function or correct this code..thanks in advance for your assistance

Comment: another algorithm i am using which                                                       function sinh=sinhx(x)
sinh=(exp(x)- exp(-1*x))/2
end                                                                                                            but again getting an error :/

Comment: As already said, the builtin function `sinh` would work, but I guess that you have a reason to wanting to write your own. Like practice or so. Anyway, can you provide the error message, I am afraid that I cannot reproduce the error. Both of the code samples runs fine for me, except that you may want to write `sinh=c/2` instead of `d=c/2` just to return the value `sinh`, matlab 2015a. Further, be careful using variables with the same name as functions. Here it is safe, but in general it may be an error source

Answer (score 1):

The simpler the better: you should use the built-in `sinh` function.

Otherwise, in your function you don't define the output variable `sinh`, hence the error.

Best